# Integer to string in C without preallocated char array

Tags: c, string, integer, heap-memory

Please, look at the following code that just convert an unsigned int to a string (there may be some unhandled cases but it's not my question), allocating  a char array in the heap and returning it, leaving the user the responsibility to free it after the use. Can you explain me why such function (and others similar) do not exist in C standard library? Yes, `printf("%s\n", itos(5))` is a memory leak, but this programming pattern is already used and is consider a good practice[1]. IMO, if such functions had existed since the dawn of C we would had little memory leaks more but **tons** of buffer overflows less!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

char* itos(unsigned int value)
{
    int string_l = (value == 0) ? 1 : (int)log10(value) + 1;
    char *string = malloc((string_l + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int residual = value;
    int it;
    for (it = string_l - 1; it >= 0; it--) {
        int digit;
        digit = residual % 10;
        residual = residual / 10;
        string[it] = '0' + digit;
    }
    string[string_l] = '\0';
    return string;
}

int main(void)
{
    char* string = itos(534534345);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

[1] http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getaddrinfo.html

EDIT:

Habbie's answer:

```
char *string;
asprintf(&string, "%d", 155);
printf("%s\n", string);
free(string);
```

Comment: are you aware of asprintf? It's in GNU libc, FreeBSD, OpenBSD and some others. see http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf

Comment: Your reference to justify small memory leaks as being considered good practice is a description of the `getaddrinfo` and `freeaddrinfo` functions. I don't get it.

Comment: @torak: wait , i'm not justifying memory leaks at all. `printf("%s\n", itos(55));` is a memory leak because I want to print the string "55", but I can't free the memory allocated for "55" because I lost the pointer to it. I just wanted to say that `getaddrinfo()` allocate space that the user have to deallocate explicitly with `freeaddrinfo()`, and that exactly the way i'd like to operate for such a trivial thing such a conversion int->string, without wasting memory such as declaring `char string[MAX_INT_DIGITS]` for "1". Read my edit.

Comment: @Habbie: wow! That's exactly what I was looking for! After an hour of googling, I was depressed of just finding references to `sprintf()`, `itoa()`, `sscanf()` regarding integer->string conversion. I'd like to vote your reply as the "accepted solution" but it seems I can't unless you post it as an answer: can you do it please? Thanks

Comment: There's no such function as `asprintf` in C standard library. The proper way to calculate the size of the required buffer in C is to use `snprintf`.

Comment: @AndreyT: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1248.pdf asprintf is proposed for the next C1X standard :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out asprintf is what you need :)

Answer (score 1):

In my eyes, memory management is up to the caller, not the callee.  For instance, when I'm not using the standard `malloc()` implementation throughout my program I would be very upset about having to find and call the corresponding `free()`, the upshot is I wouldn't use such a function.

Edit: Your `getaddrinfo()` example is perfect, they provide both `getaddrinfo()` and `freeaddrinfo()`, that's the only way to make sure I'm calling the *right* `free()`.

Comment: Just think of what happens type `MyObject *obj = new MyObject();` in c++, that's not garbage collected (as of c++98). There's an agreement between you and the constructor. The constructor tells you: "ok, I will allocate, and destructor will deallocate for you, but it's up to you to decide when to do it". Yeah, there's not a single `free()` like `delete`, and that's a problem. But strictly speaking about the integer->string conversion, the standard `free()` perfectly works for char array.

Comment: and it's up to me to decide when I call `new MyObject();` so it's *me* who initiates the allocation, and consequently it should be *me* who calls `delete`.

Comment: Ok, true. Anyway, Habbie pointed about `asprintf()` that is exactly what I was looking for, so we can be both happy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Programming has evolved since it was created - this is simply something that wasn't present since the dawn of C, but has evolved in other languages since.  I particularly like the way objective-c handles this by returning a string object which has been autoreleased (meaning it will be automatically freed later on, after the object has gone out of scope). You could implement something similar in C if you wanted to:

1. create a pool for temporary allocations outside your main loop
2. allocate from the pool as needed using your own allocation function
3. periodically free the pool at a shallow level in your call stack (for example once per cycle in your very outer main loop)

Another way to achieve the same thing, but allowing you to use system functions that use malloc to allocate memory:

1. outside your main loop create a list (initially empty) of 'to-be-freed' objects
2. write a function called 'autofree' that adds pointers to the list and returns the pointer
3. whenever you need to use it like this: `printf("%s\n", autofree(itos(5)));`
4. each time round your main loop, free all the pointers in the list and empty the list

If you do this in a nice way, you can create multiple such autofree pools and nest them around inner loops that potentially create lots of allocations that you want to be freed sooner rather than back in your main loop.